# the menu sub-item block should be full screen height

Tags: html, css, menu, popup

There is a sidebar. When you hover over the main item, a block appears with a sub-item, but its height depends on the height of the content. I can’t understand how to make the height of the block to the height of the screen, as in the photo. Please tell me.

[![enter image description here][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/28LGc.png

```css
.main {
  font-family: PT Sans;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.main_menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #38618C;
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  z-index: 1;
  user-select: none;
}

.main_menu_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.main_menu_content_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  height: 700px;
  width: 250px;
}

.main_menu_content_list li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

.main_menu_content_list a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #D7DFE8;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content_list_submenu {
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background-color: #F0F6F8;
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  transition: all linear 0.1s 0s;
  width: 250px;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.main_menu_content_list > li.main_menu_content_list_arrow > a:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 10px;
  border-color: transparent #F0F6F8 transparent transparent;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list > li.main_menu_content_list_arrow:hover > a:after{
  opacity: 1;
}

.main_menu_content_list li:hover .content_list_submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup li:not(:first-child) {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list li:hover > .content_list_submenu {
  display: flex;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: #38618C;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a:hover {
  color: #38618C;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a:active {
  color: #FF5964;
}

.main_content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="main_menu">
            <div class="main_menu_content">
                <ul class="main_menu_content_list">
                    <li class="main_menu_content_list_arrow"><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_int"></div>Интернет
                        </a>
                        <div class="content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a class="" href="">Подключение</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Дополнительные услуги</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Настройка соединения</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Подключенные дома</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Документы</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="main_menu_content_list_arrow"><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_tv"></div>Телевидение
                        </a>
                        <div class="content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a class="" href="">Подключение</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Новости</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Акции</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Аналоговое ТВ</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Оборудование</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Настройка каналов</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Подключенные дома</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Документы</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="main_menu_content_list_arrow"><a href="/content/video.html">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_video"></div>Видеонаблюдение,<br>домофон
                        </a>
                        <div class="content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a class="" href="">Подключение</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Обслуживание</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Установка</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Заявка на ремонт</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/content/rek.html">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_tvr"></div>ТВ Реклама
                        </a></li>
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_intb"></div>Интернет для бизнеса
                        </a></li>
                    <div class="main_menu_content_list_sub_block">
                        <li><a href="">Оплата</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">О компании</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <li class="main_menu_content_list_arrow"><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_sub_account"></div>Личный кабинет
                        </a>
                        <div class="content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a href="">Интернет</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Телевидение</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main_content">
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to use vh units, for example `height: 100vh`.

Comment: I tried this option (height: 100vh). Does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion:
Instead of position: aboslute on the popup use position: fixed and height 100%

```
 .content_list_submenu {
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    left: 300px;
    background-color: #F0F6F8;
    box-shadow: 10px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    transition: all linear 0.1s 0s;
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
  }
```

This will make the pop up stretch to the screen height. I also used left:300px so make it appear next to the blue sidebar.

Now the only thing left is fixing the text so it is in the middle vertically. The quickest solution I did is:

```
 .main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
```

Hope this helps